# How to validate update or select query in shell scripting?

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, shell

I am trying to validate the update or select query in shell scripting.

For example, my query is:

```
update table_name set col_name = 1 where emp_id = '1234'
```

If the code will validate the first word must be `update` and second word must be `table_name` and third word will be `set`. I tried to validate, but I am not able to get the things.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide information which DBMS you use. E.g. mysql, postgresql, sqlite?

Comment: Sql developer - oracle

Comment: It's still unclear a) how dow you use "shell scripting", b) some details about "not able to get the things"

Comment: in shell scripting i need to validate the query before update the value in database and not able to get the things means how to do like example code for this case!

Comment: Ah! So your question is: "How to use shell-scripting to execute an arbitrary SQL-statement on Oracle DB?"

Comment: Do you have `psql` command line tool at your disposal?

Comment: Please include your best attempt so people will understand what you're exactly trying to accomplish here. Otherwise this is quite vague

Comment: With an incorrect sql statement sql-developer will not update. Seems a good check.

Answer (score 0):

I created a very simple `python` script which works in v2 and v3.

Copy the content to filename.py and perform `sudo chmod +x filename.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

string = "update table_name set col_name = 1 where emp_id = '1234'"

x = string.split(' ')
if "update" != x[0]:
    print("the first word does not contain update, exiting")
    exit
else:
    print("the first word contains update")

if "update" != x[1]:
    print("the second word does not contain table_name, exiting")
    exit
else:
    print("the second word contains table_name")

if "update" != x[2]:
    print("the third word does not contain set, exiting")
    exit
else:
    print("the third word contains set")

print("we're good to go")
```

Comment: Please describe how it must: a) work with Oracle DBMS, b) be used from  `sh` or `bash` - `shell scripting` in general